# How to Optimize Parsing Json Array inside PostgreSQL function

Tags: json, postgresql, function

I wrote **PostgreSQL function** in which **JSON array** is parsed inside Loop. The Problem is it is taking too much time in case JSON Array size exceeds **1000** data. On top of that I used 2 IF statements inside loop. **Is there some ways to make it faster**.

**My code**

```
    WHILE incr < json_size LOOP
        jur_name2 := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'JUR_NAME');
        filial_code2 := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'FILIAL_CODE');
        activity_name2 := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'ACTIVITY_NAME');
        client_code2 := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'CLIENT_CODE');
        inn2 := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'INN');
        account2 := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'ACCOUNT');
        director_name2 := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'DIRECTOR_NAME');
        director_passport2 := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'DIRECTOR_PASSPORT');
        ----------------------------------
        phone_number2 := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'PHONE_NUMBER');
        reg_date2 := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'REG_DATE');
        owner_name2 := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'OWNER_NAME');
        accountant_name2 := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'ACCOUNTANT_NAME');
        terminal2 := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'TERMINAL');
        region_id2 := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'REGION_ID');
        credit_remainder := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'CREDIT_REMAINDER');
        credit_cnt   := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'CRED_CNT');
        end_date     := (SELECT CAST(my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'END_DATE' AS DATE));

        IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sp_clients WHERE client_code = client_code2)) THEN

            INSERT INTO sp_clients(jur_name,filial_code,activity_name,client_code,inn,account,director_name,director_passport,phone_number,reg_date,owner_name,accountant_name,num_of_employees,plastic_cards,terminal,region_id,client_type) 
                VALUES(jur_name2,filial_code2,activity_name2,client_code2,inn2,account2,director_name2,director_passport2,phone_number2,reg_date2,owner_name2,accountant_name2,num_of_employees2,plastic_cards2,terminal2,region_id2,cl_type);
            
            new_clients_incr := new_clients_incr + 1;
            
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO loan_portfolio(client_code,summa,cnt,oper_month) 
            SELECT client_code2,credit_remainder,credit_cnt,now()::date 
            WHERE 
                NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1 FROM loan_portfolio WHERE oper_month = now()::date AND client_code = client_code2
             );

        incr := incr + 1;

    END LOOP;
```

json

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ACTIVITY_NAME": "Gardening",
            "REGION_ID": 24,
            "FILIAL_CODE": "00760",
            "TERMINAL": 0,
            "DIRECTOR_PASSPORT": "DD12453",
            "INN": "233245",
            "REG_DATE": "2020-07-01",
            "END_DATE": "2020-06-30",
            "CRED_CNT": 6,
            "CREDIT_REMAINDER": 1.443828556508E10,
            "ACCOUNT": "24546000200199297001",
            "CLIENT_CODE": "65434234",
            "JUR_NAME": "ggg",
            "OWNER_NAME": "John Wick",
            "DIRECTOR_NAME": "Iron Man",
            "ACCOUNTANT_NAME": "Spider Man",
            "PHONE_NUMBER": "000123321"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see above code there bunch of attributes inside json array and looping through it taking much time. In addition **I created index** for columns that I check with If statements

Comment: One way to optimize is to remove the useless SELECTs: `inn2 := (SELECT my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'INN');` can be simplified to `inn2 := my_json -> 'data' ->incr ->> 'INN';`

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the JSON input as formatted text. This most certainly can be simplified to a simple `insert ... select...` using e.g. `jsonb_each()` or `jsonb_array_elements()` in the SELECT statement.

Comment: added Json example

Comment: Are there unique indexes (or constraints) on `sp_clients.client_code` and `loan_portfolio(oper_month, client_code)`?

Comment: ```sp_clients.client_code``` is unique. But ```loan_portfolio(oper_month, client_code)``` can be repeated as oper_month may vary for particular ```client_code```

Comment: But your code makes sure that the same oper_month (which seems to be a day, rather a month to begin with) is not inserted more than once for the same client_code (e.g. `('2020-07-01', 1)` may not appear two times, but you can have `(2020-07-01', 1)` and `(2020-07-02', 1)` - if this is the case you should have a unique index on `(oper_month, client_code)`

Comment: Yes you are rigth, same ```oper_month``` is not repeated more than once for one ```client_code```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single SQL statement, no loop or PL/pgSQL required

```sql
with input (data) as (
  -- your full JSON goes here
  values ('{"data": [ { ...}, {....} ]}'::jsonb)
), new_clients as (
  INSERT INTO sp_clients (jur_name,filial_code,activity_name,client_code,inn,account,director_name,director_passport,phone_number,reg_date,owner_name,accountant_name,num_of_employees,plastic_cards,terminal,region_id,client_type) 
  SELECT x.e ->> 'JUR_NAME', x.e ->> 'FILIAL_CODE', ... and so on 
  from input 
    cross join jsonb_array_elements (data -> 'data') as x(e)
  on conflict (client_code) do nothing
)
INSERT INTO loan_portfolio(client_code,summa,cnt,oper_month) 
SELECT x.e ->> 'CLIENT_CODE', x.e ->> 'CREDIT_REMAINDER', x.e ->> 'CRED_CNT', current_date
from input 
  cross join jsonb_array_elements (data -> 'data') as x(e)
on conflict (oper_month, client_code) do nothing;
```

If you want to put that into a function nevertheless and pass the JSON as a parameter, you can simplify this a bit by calling `jsonb_array_elements()` once on the parameter:

```sql
with input as (
  select x.e ->> 'CLIENT_CODE' as client_code, 
         x.e ->> 'JUR_NAME' as jur_name, 
         x.e ->> 'FILIAL_CODE' as filial_code,
         x.e ->> 'CREDIT_REMAINDER' as credit_remainder,
         x.e ->> 'CRED_CNT' as cred_cnt,
         ... repeat for all keys
  from jsonb_array_elements(p_jsonb_parameter -> 'data') as x(e)
), new_clients as (
  INSERT INTO sp_clients (jur_name,filial_code,activity_name,client_code,inn,account,director_name,director_passport,phone_number,reg_date,owner_name,accountant_name,num_of_employees,plastic_cards,terminal,region_id,client_type) 
  SELECT jur_name, filial_code, .... other columns
  from input 
  on conflict (client_code) do nothing
)
INSERT INTO loan_portfolio(client_code,summa,cnt,oper_month) 
SELECT client_code, credit_remainder, cred_cnt, current_date
from input 
on conflict (oper_month, client_code) do nothing;
```

Comment: I will check your answer now

Comment: Your answer is working really good. But I had to change ```jsonb_array_elements``` to ```json_array_elements```. I dont know the reason why ```jsonb``` is giving ```ERROR:  function jsonb_array_elements(json) does not exist```

Comment: Using `jsonb` over `json` is preferred though.

Comment: Does it depend on Postgre Version to make use of ```jsonb``` or Do I need to create extension. PostgreSQL version is : ```9.6.13```

Comment: `jsonb` was introduced in Postgres 9.4, so you can use it in Postgres 9.6 without problems. [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) "*In general, most applications should prefer to store JSON data as jsonb*"